# Messenger API Attachment using PHP Curl (Upload from File)

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger-bot

Hi guys I'm getting trouble uploading attachment in facebook messenger API
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/attachment-upload-api/

I'm using php code but I tried all possible action to upload but my code didn't work every time I send a post request I received this error

> "message":"(#100) Incorrect number of files uploaded. Must upload
> exactly one file.","type":"OAuthException","code":100"

I tried this curl pattern from the documentation

```
curl  \
  -F 'message={"attachment":{"type":"image", "payload":{"is_reusable":true}}}' \
  -F 'filedata=@/tmp/shirt.png;type=image/png' \
  "https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/me/message_attachments?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

and here's my code PHP code

```
function uploadFromFile($psid,$file) {
        $reply_message['message']['attachment'] = array(
            'type' => 'image',
            'payload' => array(
                'is_reusable' => true
            )
     );

    $reply_message['filedata'] = "@".$file['tmp_name].";type=image/png";

    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/me/message_attachments?access_token=" . $this->accessToken;
    $ch = curl_init();
    $headers = array("Content-type: application/json");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($reply_message));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,$false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $st = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    file_put_contents("errormessage-api.txt",$st);
    $result = json_decode($st,TRUE);
    $this->send($psid,$result['attachment_id']);
    return $result['attachment_id'];
}
```

I know the error is on my payload I don't know the right syntax. Thank you guys!

Comment: You can not do an HTTP file upload with `Content-type: application/json`. The _value_ of the `message` parameter is a string containing JSON, but that does not mean that the whole _request_ should be send as JSON.

Comment: thank you for your message what should I do? should I change the content-type?

Comment: If you just pass your data array to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, cURL should be able to determine the correct Content-Type on its own.